# How to say "get performed" in another way?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases, sentence, phrase-usage

> "The mechanism of warehouses can be further improved if the workload
>   of employees is lightened by certain tasks getting performed
>   autonomously."

This is the sentence I want to use, however, the term 'get performed' seems out of place. Without changing anything else in the sentence, what can I use that would be more appropriate? It's important that it's a formal word, as I will be using this in my thesis.

I looked up to see whether there were any topics that answered this question, there didn't seem to be any. I apologise if I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

**execute(d)**

> to perform a skilful action or manoeuvre

[from Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/execute)

This would be used in your example like:

> *The mechanism of warehouses can be further improved if the workload of employees is lightened by certain tasks **being executed** autonomously.*

Answer (score 0):

[Automated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automate)

> 1 : to operate by automation
>
> 2 : to convert to largely automatic operation

Thus:

> "The mechanism of warehouses can be further improved if the workload
>   of employees is lightened by certain tasks being automated."